# Is there a way to add styles specific to angular2-multiselect dropdown panel?

Tags: angular

Version: "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.6.0"

Only few styles eg: font weight is applied but not the background and color.

Below is the stackblitz for reference

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-multiselect-dropdown-npjhad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

http://cuppalabs.github.io/components/multiselectDropdown/#Configuration-Settings Here it says the classes are added to the dropdown selector tagg, but I think using more specific class names would help you. I think you need to override some of the styles in this file https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/blob/master/src/themes/default.theme.scss. Dont forget your overrides should be added after you import the default theme.